# Tens of Millions inserts into an indexed table performance/strategy (Sql Server >= 2005)

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, bigdata, sql-insert

I have to get data from many tables and combine them into a single one.
The final table will have about 120 millions rows.
I'm planning to insert the rows in the exact order needed by the big table indexes.

**My question is, in terms of performance:**
Is it better create the indexes of the new table from the start, or first make the inserts and at the end of the import create the indexes ?

Also, would it make a difference if, when building indexes at the end, the rows are already sorted in terms of indexes specifications ?

I can't test both cases and get an objective comparison since the database is on the main server which is used for many other databases and applications which can be heavy loaded or not on different moment of times. I can't restore the database to my local server either, since I don't have full access to the main server yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that copy date in first and then create your indexes. If you insert records on the table that have index, for each insert, SQL Server refresh table index. but when you create index after insert all record to your table, SQL Server don't need to refresh table index for each insert, and rebuild index one way.

You can use `SSIS` in order to copy data from source tables to destination. SSIS use balk insert and have good performance. also if you have any trigger on destination database, I suggest that disable that before start your convert.

When you create index each time on your table, rows stored in terms of your index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mehdi lotfi. I thought if I insert the rows in the exact order of the index, SQL Server would know and don't refresh table index. Voted the answer. I will come back to mark it as answer after I will be able to make comparisons.

Comment: @darkdante. please view my edit. I have a problem similar your problem 1 year ago, and solve my problem by drop all index, foreign key and disable all trigger on destination tables in first. and my copy data become 20 min duration (before use this solution, copy duration be about 5 hours).